# An autocomplete="off" example works, my code autocomplete="off" does not?

Tags: html, autocomplete

I'm trying to resolve a Chrome autocomplete aggravation with my small web based work order form.  I have tried to use autocomplete="off" in my html code, it doesn't work. When I 'Inspect' my page code in Chrome it always displays autocomplete="on" with autocomplete="off" or other wrong terms for off.

But [this user's](http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/L0e2u7v4/22/) autocomplete="off" demo works perfectly for me.  What am I missing?

My code:

```
<input name="contact_first"  style="border:1px solid #737373" 
class="required"  id="contact_first" value="<?php echo 
$row_contact['contact_first']; ?>" autocomplete="off" size="25" />
```

Example working code:

```
<label for="firstName2">First Name (WITH autocomplete):</label>
<input id="firstName2" name="firstName2" autocomplete="off">
```

I have actually cut and pasted the jsfiddle example code from the working example to a small test web form of mine, autocomplete does not stop.

This may affect other browsers also, but I use Chrome primarily.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `autocomplete="new-password"` to disable the Chrome auto-fill functionality (*different from basic autocomplete*).

Comment: Same result using autocomplete="new-password".  Right clicking on my test field(Inspect) still displays autocomplete="on".  Viewing the entire page source displays the autocomplete="new-password".

Comment: Oh ok, that means that something is changing the value of `autocomplete` during execution. Probably some Javascript, do you use some? Are you using a front-end framework?

Comment: I can't answer about the front-end framework question. I am using a modified version of this simple contacts manager though. http://www.simplecustomer.com/  I'll look for a CSS or JS that may affect this.

Comment: I don't know this php framework so I downloaded it and there is Javascript in it. With a quick search, I found the file `customers\includes\src\controls.js` that has functions like `this.element.setAttribute('autocomplete','off');` (*on line 82*). So there is a chance that it is this framework that changes the property of your field.

Comment: So, both the contact manager and my simple test form operates as expected with Opera and IE, on this same and a different PC. This feels like a Chrome thing. But I can't understand why this http://jsfiddle.net/AlexandrAbakumov/L0e2u7v4/22/  code operates as expected in Chrome.

Comment: I just found a Chrome extension installed named 'Autocomplete On'.
When I switched it off the autocomplete="off" began working.